# Install JavaFX scene builder 2.0 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: software-installation, 14.10, java, javafx

I am beginning my work on a JavaFX application for which I am using Intellij Idea ide. I have Java 8 installed on my system and I can see JavaFXSceneBuilder 1.1 in my system installed. But as I read in Oracle documentation, Java 8 comes with in-built scene-builder, unfortunately I am not able to locate it.

Because of that I see a page in the IDE for my scenebuilder even though I have provided path for 1.1 Below is the screenshot :

[image: That's where I should see scenebuilder]

Here is the path screenshot :

[image: Path screenshot]

So, why do I see that blank guy there, how can I install Scenebuilder 2.0 recommended in Intellij Idea documentation for creating JavaFX apps. Kindly let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where can i find it, after deb install?

Comment: @VasilValchev : If you are using Linux in the JDK dir.

Answer (score 4):

you can find your deb installation using following :

```
dpkg-query  -S scenebuilder
```

afterwards you can add it in intellij - it should look something like this:

```
/opt/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0
```

Answer (score 3):

So, if anyone has the same problem, go [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html) and download SceneBuilder 2.0. Specify it in "Scenebuilder path" in Settings, restart the IDE, and it will work.